# Fetching first records of sets matching a where condition in Rails

Tags: sql, ruby-on-rails, activerecord

I want to create a method for my Activity model that has many Practices called month_days_not_practiced which gives a count of the days in the current month that the Activity does not have any practices recorded for (note: days_in_month is a helper method):

```
  def month_days_not_practiced(date = Date.today)
    p = practices.where(:created_at => date.at_beginning_of_month..date.at_end_of_month).count
    days_in_month - p
  end
```

However, I want to return only one record per month day.

Can someone help me with my custom SQL (I think) please? I'm drawing a blank at the moment..

TIA!

Andy

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Put this on the end of your query:

```
.group("DATE(created_at)")
```

Comment: this baulked with a "OrderedHash can't be coerced into a Fixnum error, so I converted the resulting hash into an array as so: .group("DATE(created_at)").to_a.count and it worked

Answer (score 0):

Although you can do this with a simple `GROUP BY` operation and get the records you want, you may find this is not especially efficient since this will require a server-side sort and cannot be indexed:

```
SELECT DATE(created_at) AS on_date, COUNT(id) AS count_for_date FROM practices GROUP BY DATE(created_at)
```

This will return the number of entries indexed by day. There will be no zero entries since these will not be grouped, but as you've observed, you can always compute how many missing days there are based on how many there should be.

You can iterate over these results using the connection object:

```
Practice.connection.select_rows("...").each do |date, count|
  # ...
end
```

A way to optimize this is to simply add an indexed date column in your schema:

```
add_column :practices, :created_on, :date

execute "UPDATE practices SET created_on=created_at"

add_index :practices, :created_on
```

Be sure to assign to this field when saving your models:

```
class Practice < ActiveRecord::Base
  before_create :assign_created_on

protected
  def assign_created_on
    self.created_on = Date.today
  end
end
```

This should make your query fully indexable and much faster.

Comment: Why not index the created_at column?

Comment: Ryan's answer, with a little tweaking (see comment) was sufficient for my needs. I'm sure your answer will speed things up but right now, it's not a necessary complication. thanks all the same. cheers, andy